# Show that if language belongs to $BPP$ then also similar language belgons to $QP$

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, probabilistic-algorithms

> Prove that for each arbitrary set of natural numbers $A$ we have:
>   $$\{bin(n) | n\in A\} \in BPP \to \{0^n|n\in A\}\in QP$$ where $bin
> (n)$ is binary representation of $n$ $$QP = \bigcup_{c\in \mathbb{N}}
>  DTIME\left(2^{(\log n)^c}\right) $$

I have no idea how to move from probablistic machines to non-probablisitic machine. Any ideas ?

**Edit**
Let us note, that $DTIME(n)\subseteq QP$, because for $c=1$ we have $2^{\log n}=n$.  Now we use the fact that $BPP\subset EXP$.  Let $X=\{bin(n)|n\in A\}$ will be decided by exponetnial turing machine $M$.

Now, we give machine $N$ which in $DTIME(n)$ (so in particular in $QP$) recognize  $Y=\{0^n | n\in A\}$.
The $N$ works in following way:
1. Convert unary ($n$ bits) number to binary number ($\log n$) bits.
2. Launch $M$ on this converted input - it takes $2^{\log n}=n$ steps.
3. $n\in DTIME(n)\subseteq QP$.

Comment: Can you put $BPP$ in $EXP$? Can you think of how does this help you here?

Comment: @Ariel I edited and added my thoughts. I think that it does work, however I am not sure why $BPP\subset EXP$. Can you check my thoughts and clarify $BPP\subset EXP$ ?

Comment: $EXP=\bigcup\limits_{c} 2^{n^c}$, so $M$ might run in $2^{n^c}$ time, and thus your solution puts $Y$ in $QP$ rather than in linear time.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. Sol solution is almost ok.  What about $BPP\subset EXP$ ?

Comment: @JamesHollis, QP has nothing with quantumness, it means quasipolynomial.